# React.js Flux add, make Client's Browser automatic update to latest code

Tags: reactjs

Right now when we deploy new versions of our server and client code to production we have to tell every single user to do a hard refresh in their browser to get the latest code.

This is really annoying to our users, having to constantly tell them or ask them "Did you refresh?" or "Did you hard refresh?"

It should be automatic. With other web technologies this wouldn't be a problem, but with React.js Cache stores etc it is very difficult.

Answer (score -2):

This sounds like an issue not with React, but with your caching mechanism. If you need users to do a hard refresh then something is going wrong with how you cache your site.

If you can't make any changes to caching then why don't you store a hash of your bundle on the client and when they enter the site, compare that with the latest hash, if they're the different then request a few set of code down from the site.

Comment: Thanks for your post. We do nothing to make the browser cache, not cache. This is 1000% a React.js thing. I have made many Java Enterprise web sites in my life and this is the 1st to ever not automatically update the UI side of things when we deployed.

I don't understand what you mean about hash of your bundle?

Comment: The browser will not automatically download a new bundle.js when you deploy the new code.